# Magento2 Get Simple SKU When AddToCart

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento2

I am trying to get the SKU of a simple product when adding to cart.
I have a configurable product which has 3 size options S,M,L. Each has its own SKU, When I select a size and click Add To Cart I want to get the sku of the simple product.

I have looked at the js file catalog-add-to-cart.js it does not return the simple sku only the configurable sku.

However in the console there is a response from http://mywebsite.com/customer/section/load/?sections=cart%2Cmessages&update_section_id=true

which does contain the simple sku.

Could someone please advise me a way of quickly capturing the simple sku?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I used this little tweak in order to get the SKU of the Simple product and not the configurable one if there is multiple sizes or color

```
//By default, use the default product image
$path = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image');

//BUT
//If there is multiple colors/sizes
if (is_array($product["_cache_instance_products"])){
   //For each product in the inventory
   foreach ($product["_cache_instance_products"] as $_prod ) {
     //check if the SKU match with the one of the article in the Cart
     if($_prod["sku"]==$product->getSku()){
        //check if this product have various color
        if (isset($_prod["small_image"])){
           //if so, take the specific image
           $path = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_prod, 'small_image');
           }
        }
     }
 }
```

This piece of code is placed in : *shop/app/code/community/Mdl/Ajaxcheckout/controllers/IndexController.php*

I hope it will help you

Comment: Hi Lucas, Thanks for the reply. I don't believe your solution will work for me as it seems to be for Magento 1.x but I'm using 2.x

Comment: Ow I didn't know that it was that different. Sorry for this. Hope you'll find out